# 2018 MacBook Pro keeps crashing - macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, crash, kernel-panic

Recently my Mac has been crashing for no apparent reason. I have zero knowledge of how to interpret the crash report and was hoping someone here could shed light on it. Here is the report:

```
Fri Mar 13 20:22:05 2020
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f88d5b71f): "sfree on invalid allocation at 0xffffff8031888130"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Sandbox_executables/Sandbox-765.70.1/src/kext/smalloc.c:248
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9128273330 : 0xffffff8007c6ce56 
0xffffff9128273380 : 0xffffff8007d963e4 
0xffffff91282733c0 : 0xffffff8007d885b4 
0xffffff9128273430 : 0xffffff8007c1ee60 
0xffffff9128273450 : 0xffffff8007c6c8cc 
0xffffff9128273580 : 0xffffff8007c6c68c 
0xffffff91282735e0 : 0xffffff7f88d5b71f 
0xffffff9128273610 : 0xffffff7f88d4a19c 
0xffffff9128273630 : 0xffffff7f88d5f773 
0xffffff9128273650 : 0xffffff7f88d523bd 
0xffffff9128273690 : 0xffffff7f88d52172 
0xffffff91282736c0 : 0xffffff80083027c4 
0xffffff91282736e0 : 0xffffff80080ecc5d 
0xffffff9128273700 : 0xffffff8007e8812f 
0xffffff9128273750 : 0xffffff8007ea1b58 
0xffffff9128273b30 : 0xffffff80080e6f60 
0xffffff9128273b90 : 0xffffff8007ea2ba9 
0xffffff9128273bb0 : 0xffffff8007ec2340 
0xffffff9128273bf0 : 0xffffff8007eb1047 
0xffffff9128273f10 : 0xffffff8007eb18df 
0xffffff9128273f40 : 0xffffff8008203e88 
0xffffff9128273fa0 : 0xffffff8007c1f646 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kext.AppleMatch(1.0d1)[2D2996CA-A15E-39E6-9D6B-2BE6DF131972]@0xffffff7f88d49000->0xffffff7f88d4dfff
         com.apple.security.sandbox(300.0)[BDFF700A-6746-3643-A0A1-852628695B04]@0xffffff7f88d4e000->0xffffff7f88d6efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[1F788291-6344-37F1-802C-7E74F8822B4B]@0xffffff7f88d34000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AppleMatch(1.0.0d1)[2D2996CA-A15E-39E6-9D6B-2BE6DF131972]@0xffffff7f88d49000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[F27A8A2A-6662-3608-83BD-415037509E01]@0xffffff7f88713000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: fseventsd

Mac OS version:
17G11023

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jan 23 07:05:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-4570.71.69~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D8347098-9B31-3C8E-A1C9-CA857F05BB97
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007b00000
System model name: MacBookPro14,1 (Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 64254073431713
last loaded kext at 13658031224728: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8b2c6000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 14158059474433: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8b2ae000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.malwarebytes.mbam.rtprotection  4.0.30
com.symantec.ips.kext   9.0.1
com.symantec.nfm.kext   9.0.0
com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext  9.0.2
com.symantec.SymXIPS    9.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.17
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 135
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1242.32.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   186
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.17
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 683.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.7f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.21
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.28
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.17
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.17
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.23
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1614.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 135
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.7f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1614.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1614.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    53.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  53.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: There's not much we can do with a single panic log. With two logs it might be possible to identify similarities. But without a reproducible test case, it will be hard to provide an answer.

Comment: Well, having two antiviruses potentially fighting each other is unlikely to be a good thing.

Comment: Try booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to disable your 3rd party kexts.  I'm with @Tetsujin - having malwarebytes *and* Symantec running simultaneously is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do any of you have an opinion on which is better to keep? Maywarebytes or Norton? We had horrible hacking, DOS attacks, etc. last year and went into a lockdown mode. Thanks again for the help. If I get another crash report today, I will post it here too.

Comment: Neither are going to prevent [external] hackers or DDoS attacks, so take your pick. You need to harden your external firewall/gateway to prevent that kind of attack from outside the building.

Comment: Tetsujin - thanks! Yes we have been able to lock down the gateway too so I guess we will just have to let one of the programs go and hopefully that will take care of the crashing. I didn't know neither program helps with hacking. I now wonder what they are good for.

Comment: Mainly they're good for finding Windows viruses & preventing them being spread innocently to Windows users ;)